# Create an Apache SetEnv variable with the value of a subclaim

Tags: apache, setenv, setenvif

I have an environment variable called FIRST and containing a JSON :

{ 
    "claim1": "val1", 
    "claim2": "val2" 
}

I would like to set a new environment variable which should contain only val1.

I tried to set this new variable (SECOND) using SetEnvIf but unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
SetEnvIf FIRST (\"claim1\":)(.*?)\"(.*?)\" SECOND=$3
```

The regex is correct, you can check it here : [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wa7PJP/9)

The FIRST variable is not a request attribute even if it seems to be required according to the [Apache Module mod_setenvif documentation.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_setenvif.html).

Any idea how I could achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: try changing to `SECOND=$1`

Comment: I tried this but it's still not working for me. The SECOND variable is empty.

Comment: regex is missing a space after the `:`. try `(?:"claim1": ")(.*?)(?:")` .[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wa7PJP/1)

Comment: A better regex would be `(?:"claim1" *: *")([^"]+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wa7PJP/2) . This should handle spaces.

Comment: Apache seems to refuse the Regex (even if it is correct according to the link below). I have the following error message '"SetEnvIf Regex could not be compiled"

Comment: try escaping the double quotes: `(?:\"claim1\" *: *\")([^\"]+)` .[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wa7PJP/6)

Comment: I still get the error message. With the following syntax: `SetEnvIf FIRST (\"claim1\":)(.*?)\"(.*?)\" SECOND=$3` I don't get the error message below but the SECOND variable is empty. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried `(?:"claim1": ")(.*?)(?:")` with `SECOND=$1`?

Comment: Yes I tried this but I get the error message below.